# How to find the lagrange multipliers of a problem in Gurobi + Matlab, is there any commands?

Tags: matlab, gurobi, cvx

In LP or other kinds of programming, cvx + Matlab may get the lagrange multipliers with easy codes, but is there any commands for Gurobi to achieve things like this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://or.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Gurobi's Matlab API, the optimization call will return a single data instance that contains all results from that optimization, including the dual values: [Matlab API](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/matlab_grb.html)

You would need to inspect this returned data object to find the values you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I also found out that with YALMIP (which I use to call Gurobi) there is also 'dual' command to solve this.